# How many giant planets could form in a hierarchical triple star system?

Tags: planets, orbital-mechanics, astronomy, astrophysics, gas-giants

The system in question has a very close binary pair of 2 G-type stars, a G9V and a G7V, orbiting at about 0.2 AU, with a K2V star in a far orbit about 300 AU out around the both of them. There is a Class Y Brown Dwarf orbiting the pair at about 1.4 AU.

I am wondering potentially how many giant planets you could potentially pack into a system, or if multiple stars tend to hog most of the matter for themselves? Gas giants I kinda like the idea of, but smaller gas dwarfs or super-earths are also fine. I am intending for these planets to be what terrestrial rocky planets orbit, having all been scooped up by various large objects over the course of the system's life.

I am hoping for something in the realm of possibility, but implausibility is ok, as long as things wouldn't tear themselves apart and things are stable.

Comment: This will be awkward to answer well... planetary system formation is still somewhat poorly understood. I will say that the stars hugging all the supply of matter isn't an issue so much as giant planets gravitationally interacting with other planets and hurling them out into interstellar space.

Comment: We don't know enough about the universe (meaining: other star systems, especially of the specific type you're referencing) to give you a sensible answer. Please remember, we can't give you real-world answers to imaginary conditions, but we can give you imaginary answers to imaginary conditions. From that perspective (and thanks to Chaos Theory), there's nothing stopping you from having exactly what you want so long as the initial gas cloud was large and dense enough. Thus, the answer to the question "is this believable?" is yes.

Comment: (NOTE: The inconvenient reality of chaos theory is that it's more likely for a cloud large enough to form a triple-star system and some X number of gas giants to form multiple star systems with smaller planets. But that means your star system is special, cool, and deserving to exist if only in fiction.)